# Confused about Telescoping/Domain Transformation Question

Tags: algorithms

I have been working on the following domain transformation problem however, I am stuck on how to continue to receive the solution. I would greatly appreciate it if someone can explain how I can complete this:

T(1) = 0

T(n) = T(n/2) + n^2

The following is what I have so far: 
[image: my work so far]

Comment: It looks like your telescoping summation is wrong. $2^{2k}+2^{2k-2}+ \cdots = k$? Can you double check?

Comment: I don't think it's right either, I'm a little confused on how to fix it though, I was trying to understand it in class but the telescoping method is still kind of new to me.

Comment: That seems right but if you don't mind, how did you get to the following? :)

Comment: $S(0)=T(2^0)=T(1)=0$. $(2^{k})^2+(2^{k-1})^2+ \cdots + 2^2= 2^{2k}+2^{2k-2}+ \cdots + 2^2= \frac {2^{2k+2}-4}{3}$

Comment: would that replace the line of S(k)? Because I'm confused to how I'd relay the right summation in the format I have above

Comment: Is my answer below clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can write the telescope more clearly.

$$\begin{array}{ll}
S(k)-S(k-1)\phantom{S(k-2)-S(k-3)S(2)-S(1)-S(0)}&=(2^{k})^2\\
\phantom{S(k)-}S(k-1)-S(k-2)\phantom{-S(k-3)S(2)-S(1)-S(0)}&=(2^{k-1})^2\\
\phantom{S(k)-S(k-1)}S(k-2)-S(k-3)\phantom{S(2)-S(1)-S(0)}&=(2^{k-2})^2\\
\phantom{S(k)-S(k-1)S(k-2)}\cdots\phantom{S(2)-S(1)-S(0)}&\cdots\\
\phantom{S(k)-S(k-1)-S(k-2)-S(k-3)}S(2)-S(1)\phantom{-S(0)}&=(2^{2})^2\\
\phantom{S(k)-S(k-1)-S(k-2)-S(k-3)S(2)-}S(1)-S(0)&=(2^{1})^2\\
\end{array}$$
Summing up all equalities above, we will cancel all terms between one another except the first term and the last term. We have
$$\begin{align}
S(k)-S(0) 
&= (2^{k})^2+(2^{k-1})^2+(2^{k-2})^2+ \cdots + (2^2)^2 + 2^2\\
&= 2^{2k}+2^{2k-2}+2^{2k-4}+ \cdots +2^4+ 2^2\\
&= \frac {2^{2k+2}-4}{3}
\end{align}$$
So $$S(k)=\frac {2^{2k+2}\ -4}{3}+S(0) = \frac {2^{2k+2}\ -4}{3} = \frac {4(2^{k})^2\ -4}{3}$$

Now substitute $\log_2n$ for $k$. Note $2^k=n$.
$$S(\log_2n)=\frac43(n^2-1)$$
The left side is $T(2^{\log_2n})=T(n)$. So 
$$T(n)=\frac43(n^2-1)$$
The equality holds only when $n=2^k$ for some nonnegative integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
  0 & n = 1\\
  T\left(\tfrac{n}{2}\right) + n^2 & n > 1
\end{cases}$$

You are then correct, let $n = 2^k$. We can then rewrite $S(k) = T(2^k)$ as:

$$S(k) = \begin{cases}
  0 & k = 0 \quad \text{because } 2^0 = 1\\
  S\left(k-1\right) + 2^{2k} & k > 0
\end{cases}$$

This then immediately turns into the sum:

$$\begin{align*}
S(k) &= \sum_{i = 1}^k 2^{2i}\\
     &= \sum_{i = 1}^k 4^i\\
     &= \frac{4^{k+1} - 1}{3} - 1 & \text{by geometric sum rules}
\end{align*}$$

We can then plug $n$ back in such that $k = \log_2 n$:

$$\begin{align*}
T(n) & = S(\log_2 n) \\
& = \frac{4^{\log_2 n + 1} - 1}{3} - 1\\
& = \frac{4 \cdot 2^{2\log_2 n} - 1}{3} - 1\\
& = \frac{4 n^2 - 1}{3} - 1\\
& = O(n^2)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence can be written
$$\begin{cases}S(0)=1=4^0\\S(k)=S(k-1)+4^k\end{cases}$$
and you should recognize the sum of a geometric series, by

$$S(k)=S(k-1)+4^k=S(k-2)+4^{k-1}+4^k=S(k-3)+4^{k-2}+4^{k-1}+4^k=\cdots\\=S(0)+4^1+\cdots4^{k-1}+4^k=\frac{4^{k+1}-1}3=\frac{4(2^k)^2-1}3=\frac{4n^2-1}3.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution "manually" by successive doublings and by writing the recurrence as

$$\frac{T(n)}{n^2}=\frac{T\left(\dfrac n2\right)}{n^2}+1.$$

The sums are

$$\frac{T(1)}1=1,\\\frac{T(2)}4=\frac14+1,\\\frac{T(4)}{16}=\frac1{16}+\frac14+1,\\\frac{T(8)}{64}=\frac1{64}+\frac1{16}+\frac14+1,\\\cdots$$

The RHS quickly tend to $\dfrac13$ and $T(n)=\Theta(n^2).$